# get matching text in dynamically changing tags

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string in which the values of href and text in tags is dynamically changing .

for example teh text i have is this

```
-5></span>
</span>
                    <a class=header-3 href=/mercedes-benz/190-class/1993/consumer-reviews/e-bay-find.html?style=2286&sub=&reviewId=202661771>DYNAMIC changing text</a>
```

I wish to take the value of href only i.e in this case

`/mercedes-benz/190-class/1993/consumer-reviews/e-bay-find.html?style=2286&sub=&reviewId=202661771`

Comment: [What is the best way to parse html in C#? {closed}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623786/regular-expression-getting-url-value-from-hyperlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var links =doc.DocumentNode
              .Descendants("a")
              .Select(n => n.Attributes["href"].Value).ToArray();
```